# How to create a POST OS custom task sequence for an out-of-the box laptop

Tags: windows-7, imaging, mdt-2012, mdt

I'm playing around with MDT with the intent of facilitating the rollout of new laptops.

As we turn on the new laptop for the first we want to go through with the standard windows OEM installation.

Afterwards we just want to run a post os task sequence from the deployment share that presents the deployment wizard and prompts us for the exact same parameters as a new deployment

- Hostname
- Domain Joining Credentials
- OU
- Local admins
- Install applications list

Basically the task sequence should only join the domain, install apps **without** actually installing an operating system. We are using the Windows 7 OEM that comes with the laptop and run litetouch.vbs within windows.

I'm having issues calling the deployment wizard script in my post os task sequence. How exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The wizard in MDT that allows you to name the computer, join the domain and add users are all functions that are inserted into the answer file that would be used during setup. This will not work in your situation, since you are booting the system in order to call the Post OS Installation task. You would have to create custom scripts to make those changes. In MDT, you can add the step ‘Run PowerShell Script’ or ‘Run command Line’ depending on which method you use for scripting. If you search the MDT help files for ‘Run PowerShell script’ and there are several topics to help you. I also found [this page in the TechNet Script Center](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Join-a-computer-to-a-domain-6e19d905) for joining a computer to a domain with Powershell and this TechNet Wiki article ‘[Set Computer Name using PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7824.set-computer-name-using-powershell.aspx)’ that may be of help.

Hope this helps,